# How do I send the Child Content from a Reusable Component using @Input

Tags: angular

Using Angular 12.

I want to create a re-usable button component. I want to get the text inside the tags of where I host my component and then get it as an Input inside my component.

**Inside my home.component.html:**

```
<app-ui-text-button color="#fe7f2d">Press Me!</app-ui-text-button>
```

I want to get *Press Me!* text and send it as an Input to my component.

**My Component:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-ui-text-button',
    styles: [`
            .button {
                padding: 12px 8px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .button:hover {
                filter: brightness(1.2);
            }
        `],
    template: `
        <div class="button" [style.backgroundColor]="color" (click)="onClick($event)">{{ text }}</div>
    `
}
)
export class AppUiTextButtonComponent {

    // Inputs
    @Input() text = 'sdfs';
    @Input() color = '#619b8a';
    // @Input() childContent: ElementRef<any> = new ElementRef(any);

    // Outputs
    @Output() clicked = new EventEmitter<any>();

    onClick(event: Event) {
        this.clicked.emit(event);
    }
}
```

So I want to grab the text and insert it as dynamic variable inside my div.

**I have tried**

```
@Input() childContent: ElementRef<any> = new ElementRef(any);
@Input() text = '';
```

wihtout success.
I also tried to search online, but not getting any clear answers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you please make a stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: You're looking for the term "content projection" and `ng-content`. You'll find resources for that in the Angular docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1: simple method**

if you want the text in your custom component. you can do it as

```
<app-ui-text-button color="#fe7f2d" [text]="Press Me!"></app-ui-text-button>
```

then `text` @Input will have `Press Me!` in your component!

**Method 2: using content projection**

ui-text-button.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-ui-text-button',
    styles: [`
            .button {
                padding: 12px 8px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .button:hover {
                filter: brightness(1.2);
            }
        `],
    template: `
        <div class="button" [style.backgroundColor]="color" (click)="onClick($event)">
<ng-content></ng-content> <!-- here added this ng-content tag -->
</div>
    `
}
)
export class AppUiTextButtonComponent {

    // Inputs
   // @Input() text = 'sdfs'; // don't need this anymore with content projection
    @Input() color = '#619b8a';
    // @Input() childContent: ElementRef<any> = new ElementRef(any);

    // Outputs
    @Output() clicked = new EventEmitter<any>();

    onClick(event: Event) {
        this.clicked.emit(event);
    }
}
```

now using this `ui-text-button` as you want to use in your example

```
<app-ui-text-button color="#fe7f2d">Press Me!</app-ui-text-button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew about method 1, but wanted the 2nd method. Can't believe it was that easy.